# Using fetch inside my own hook - showing loader inside a return()

Tags: javascript, reactjs

useFetch hook:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';

const useFetch = (url, options) => {
  const [response, setResponse] = useState(null);
  const [error, setError] = useState(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    (async () => {
      try {
        const res = await fetch(url, options);
        const json = await res.json();
        setResponse(json);
      } catch (error) {
        setError(error);
      }
    })();
  }, [url]);

  return { response, error };
};

export default useFetch;
```

Then i'm using this hook, inside my component:

```
const Example = () => {
  const res = useFetch('some_URL');

  if (!res.response) {
    return <div>Loading...</div>;
  }
  const data = res.response.data;

  return (
    <>
      ...Mapping data array here, also i want to show loader here.
    </>
  )
}
```

As you can see, using `fetch()` inside a custom hook, i have to explicitly check `if (!res.response)` otherwise, i'll get an errors regards `data` is undefined. Can i set my loader inside a `return()` so it would look more cleaner?

Also should i use a custom hook for a fetch method? Or it's better to use it as a plain function?

**UPDATED PART OF MY COMPONENT**

```
const Example = () => {
  const res = useFetch('some_URL');
  const data = res.response.data;

  return data ? (
    <>
      {
        data.map(......);
      }
    </>
  ) : (
    <>Loading...</>
  );
}
```

This gives me an error: `Cannot read property 'data' of null` and stops rendering at all.

Comment: You can have one more status in your custom hook informing about the status of the fetch and you can use that to show the loader.

Comment: It is not good. Every time your website is updated it will rerender your "custom hook".
Just implement directly the fetching in useEffect.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would do something like this:

```js
const Example = () => {
    const { response, error } = useFetch('some_URL');

    return (response ?
        <div>{response.data}</div> :
        <div>Loading...</div>
    );
}
```

Or use [`useMemo`](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usememo) hook to make it more readable and optimized:

```js
const Example = () => {
    const { response, error } = useFetch('some_URL');

    const content = useMemo(() => {
        if (response) {
            return response.data;
        } else {
            return 'Loading...';
        }
    }, [response]);

    return (
        <div>{content}</div>
    );
}
```

---

Here's an example that creating a dedicated hook for specific data fetching:

#### users.js

```js
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';

export const useUserData = id => {
    const [userData, setUserData] = useState(null);

    useEffect(() => {
        (async () => {
            try {
                const res = await fetch('/users/', { id });
                const json = await res.json();
                setUserData(json);
            } catch (error) {
                setUserData(undefined);
            }
        })();
    }, [id]);

    return userData;
}
```

#### Example.jsx

```js
import React from 'react';
import { useUserData } from 'users';

export default Example = () => {
    const userData = useUserData(1);

    return (userData ?
        <div>{userData.name}</div> :
        <div>Loading...</div>
    );
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but how do you deal with data fetching yourself? Using a wrapper as custom hook, or just a custom function?

Comment: That depends, if it's some data that persist in various places. You should consider using a global state management library.

Comment: No, i mean when u're using `fetch` or other 3rd party xhr library, do you wrap it? Or just use it in a component's `useEffect()` hook or `componentDidMount()`?

Comment: @AlexanderKim Pretty much the same idea as yours. But maybe wrap them in other hooks that do data fetching. Avoid exposing the server API details in components themselves.

Comment: Your example.jsx would throw an error, because userData is not resolved yet.

Comment: @AlexanderKim It doesn't have to be resolved. The value is `null` at first. After it resolves, it automatically switches to the resolved value. And `userData.name` will not be executed before it has value.

Comment: Cannot read property 'userData' of null it gives. And doesn't render, nor name, nor Loading text.

Comment: @AlexanderKim Did you accidentally write `const { userData } = ...` instead of `const userData = ...`?

Comment: Nope, i understand the difference. Updated my question. Btw, your part with `return (userData ?` seems like invalid syntax, because we have to use braces inside return in order to fire js expression.

Comment: @AlexanderKim It should work fine, here's the live example: https://jsfiddle.net/2oepg7L1/